# How to do filtering in Django Rest ModelViewset

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have signup api. I'm adding signup details, data adding fine but I don't want to add same data multiple time.For example username="abc",  email= "abc@example.com",  phone_no="1234567890"  data already present in database but its adding same data again and again. I'm trying to avoid this. How to do that

modes.py

```
class Signup(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True, null=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
```

serializers.py

```
class SignupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Signup
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
class SignupViews(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Signup.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SignupSerializer
```

urls.py

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('api/signup', views.SignupViews)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls))
]
```

Comment: So, what you want is basically update the data after signing up? I couldn't understand your question

Comment: Why not use the default Django `User` model?

Comment: @HigorRossato I have Signup api. I don't want to add same username multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a unique constraint to `username`:

```
class Signup(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Note that you can't have `max_length` greater than 255.

Also, you can't have a unique constraint on a `CharField` that has blank=True

Lastly, Why not use the Django `User` model for this?